# How to save user in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I can't find the answer to this problem which I guessed was very easy for Django.

I simply want to define an `author` field in a model, like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

It seems there is no easy way like `author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=current_user)` so what is the easiest way to store the currently logged in user in the database? (if not logged in, a pre-defined default user called "anonymous" can be used)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Currently logged user is available in the view as the `request.user` attribute:

```
def create_article(request):
   ...
   if request.user.is_active():
       article.author = request.user                          
   article.save()
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks. So I want to make sure that I cannot do this by only changing the models?

Comment: i'd modify slightly further and/or use `request.user.is_active()`

Comment: No, you can't do this at model level.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can pass `request.user` to your form class and override the save:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Allows you to pass the user in from the request, or just set the property
        if not hasattr(self, 'user'):
            self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True)
        article = super(ArticleForm, self).save(commit=False)
        article.user = self.user
        if commit:
            article.save()
        return article
```

Slightly more code, but it's encapsulated in the form class and not in the view, so you can use it in more than one place.

Example usage:

```
# in a view
@login_required
def your_view(request):
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user)
    . . .

# in Django admin
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = ArticleForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(ArticleAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.user = request.user
        return form
```

In either use case, you can be assured you have an authenticated user.